# Round to few decimals and re-arrange column values of a file

Tags: bash, decimal

I have a file consists many lines of data as below.

```
$cat out.txt

342000,0,6.768619883040936,5.834888120763486,12211.2329060592,14437.0
342001,1,7.768619883040937,6.834888120763487,12212.2329060593,14438.1
........
........
```

I need to reformat the data as below and update the same file.

```
342000,0,6.769,5.835,12211,14437
342001,1,7.769,6.835,12212,14438
```

Required;

1. Column 3 values round to 3 decimals
2. Column 4 values round to 3 decimals
3. Round off decimals for Column 5 values
4. Round off decimals for Column 6 values

Appreciate your support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk` with `printf` as shown below:

```
$ awk -F, '{printf("%d,%d,%.3f,%.3f,%.0f,%.0f\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)}' file
342000,0,6.769,5.835,12211,14437
342001,1,7.769,6.835,12212,14438
```

Comment: note to others: if your fields are not separated by `,` then omit `-F,`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this entirely in bash (`printf` is a builtin), you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

IN=$1

(
    IFS=','
    while read line ; do
        set $line XXX
        if [ $1 != "XXX" ] ; then
            printf "%d,%d,%.3f,%.3f,%.0f,%.0f\n" "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6"
        fi
    done
) < $IN
```

Comment: This is working nicely. Thanks for your support. BTW I have used awk solution since it is convenient (a single liner) for me.

Answer (score 1):

this could be simplified, also note to set the decimal separator in the right locale.

```
export LANG=C
```

and you could do something like this (knowing the format is fixed of your input)

```
IFS=","
while read line;do printf "%d,%d,%.3f,%.3f,%.0f,%.0f\n" $line ; done < out
```

Comment: This is working nicely. Thanks for your support. BTW I have used awk solution since it is convenient (a single liner) for me.